# formatting query results using oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I want to format query results in oracle and save them into an output file.

I tried this query:

```
spool "result.txt"
SELECT STA_CODE,DATE_CREATION,DATE_FIN_INSTANCE,DATE_FIN_TRAITEMENT  FROM DEMANDE;
spool off;
```

In my output file, the result looks like:

```
STA_CODE                  DATE_CRE DATE_FIN DATE_FIN

------------------------- -------- -------- --------

200                       09/05/17 09/05/17 09/05/17 

400                       09/05/17 09/05/17 09/05/18
```

I want then to write a java code that takes for each line the result and match it with name of column: for example STA_CODE=200, STA_CODE=400, DATE_CRE=09/05/17, DATE_CRE=09/05/18 ....
I'm biginner in JAVA and I can't write that Bit of code. Is possible to directly format query results and then parse the output file without doing any transformation with java.

Comment: Not really sure how you want the output to look from the query. Is it all the STA_CODE values then all the DATE_CRE values and so on ?

Comment: Yes.. looks like cle=value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want each row separated, then use

```
SELECT 'STA_CODE='||STA_CODE
 ||', DATE_CRE=' ||to_date(DATE_CREATION,'DD/MM/YY')---other values 
from DEMANDE
```

If you want all `STA_CODE` first and then all `DATE_CRE` and then other columns in one line, separated by comma, use something like

```
select listagg(col1,', ') within group (order by seq)
from (
SELECT 1 as seq,'STA_CODE='||STA_CODE as col1 from DEMANDE
union
SELECT 2 as seq,'DATE_CRE='||to_date(DATE_CREATION,'DD/MM/YY') from DEMANDE
union 
---- other select queryies separated by union.

)
```

NOTE: You cannot guarantee order among each row. So it might happen that second `STA_CODE` come first and first `DATE_CRE` come second. To garuntee that, order by a column in all `union` queries.

Comment: IT's okey..Thanks !